# AlignAbsolute on QGraphicsGridLayout

Tags: qt, layout, qt4

I have four QGraphicsLinearLayout items all contaning bunch of QGraphicsWidgetItems.
I have one QGraphicsGridLayout item.

Is it possible to align linear layouts on grid to absolute positions. If possible how?

Answer (score 0):

What about [`QGraphicsGridLayout::setColumnAlignment( int column, Qt::Alignment  alignment )`](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qgraphicsgridlayout.html#setColumnAlignment)?

Comment: It is not working for me. I do not understand why it does not work. But I am trying.